# How can I join a third table into the result of two joint tables?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I was writing a python program to read the names of columns and the type of the columns need to satisfied.

I want to place the results like this:

```
id_index=Column(int)
```

by using print

```
print "{0}{1}=Column({2})".format(" "*5,SysColumns.name,SysTypes.xtype)
```

I will use three tables： `SysColumns`, `SysObjects`, and `SysTypes`:

```
class SysColumns(BaseModel):
     __tablename__ = "SysColumns"
     name=Column(String,primary_key=True)
     colorder=Column(Integer,primary_key=True)
     id=Column(Integer,primary_key=True)
     xtype = Column(String, primary_key=True) 

class SysObjects(BaseModel):
     __tablename__ = "SysObjects"
     name=Column(String)
     id=Column(Integer,primary_key=True)
     xtype=Column(String,primary_key=True)

class SysTypes(BaseModel):
    __tablename__ = "SysTypes"
    name = Column(String, primary_key=True)
    xtype = Column(String)
```

`SysColumns` has the same column `id` in `SysObjects`, while `SysTypes` has the same  column `xtype` in `SysColumns`.

The original code is as below:

```
def dispMod(session,tableName):
    result=session.query(SysColumns). \
        join(SysObjects,SysColumns.id==SysObjects.id).\
            filter(SysObjects.xtype=='u').\
            filter(SysObjects.name==tableName).\
            order_by(SysColumns.colorder)

    for sysColumns in result:
        print "{0}{1}=Column({2})".format(" "*5,SysColumns.name,SysColumns.xtype)
```

The result can be displayed like:

```
id_index=Column(56)
```

Now I need to search the number 56 in `SysTypes` to change it in to the type it stand for.

`SysTypes` has columns of `SysTypes.xtype` and `SysTypes.name`.
I want it to show me the name instead of the `xtype`:

```
print "{0}{1}=Column({2})".format(" "*5,SysColumns.name,Systypes.name)
```

I don't know how to use the result above to join the Systypes table to find the name in it.

Can I write the query to search `SysColumns.name` and `SysTypes.name` for one time?

Comment: What exactly are you really trying to accomplish? It seems you're generating code from your data, but why?

Comment: Yes,I will use the data type and column name in another programe,I don't want to copy and paste one by one from the database. So  I'd like to generate code from my database.so that will be more efficient in my work.

Comment: But why? What is the end goal? Perhaps some existing tools might be better suited to your task already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add the join after the other and select the names only:

```
session.query(SysColumns.name, SysTypes.name).\
    join(SysObjects, SysColumns.id == SysObjects.id).\
    join(SysTypes, SysTypes.xtype == SysColumns.xtype).\
    filter(SysObjects.xtype == 'u').\
    filter(SysObjects.name == tableName).\
    order_by(SysColumns.colorder)
```

Comment: There are some strange in these tables. The xtype in SysObjects is not as the same as the what are in SysTypes. But the xtype in SysColumns are the same as xtype in Systypes.                                                                  So, should I  change the code "join(SysTypes, SysObjects.xtype == SysTypes.xtype).\" into " join(SysTypes, SysColumns.xtype == SysTypes.xtype).\"?

Comment: Was that correct after all? From reading "SysTypes has the same column xtype in SysColumns" I changed the join to `join(SysTypes, SysTypes.xtype == SysColumns.xtype).`.